# Default Parameter Transformer does not kick in, when using {string} in a sentence

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Hope you can help me out here.
Recently we have converted our steps to use {int}  and {string} etc in the sentences.
However, it seems the default parameter transformed does not kick in any longer, when using this.

In other words, when I formulate my sentence as :
@Given("^terminal "([^"]*)" is connected$")

it works fine (meaning, the parameter does through the ParameterTypes.defaultTransformer, the argument is converted, and the converted value lands as a string into the method terminalIsConnected(String terminalLogicalId).

However, after conversion to:
@Given("terminal {string} is connected")
the parameter never does through the ParameterTypes.defaultTransformer. The method terminalIsConnected(String terminalLogicalId) receives the UNtransformed value.

Is there anyone that knows how to solve this?

---

This is the feature file:

Scenario: Check step argument transformation

```
Given the query parameters
  | workstationid | 123123123 |
Then store result for query "CHECK_WORKSTATION_ID.sql" in memory with tag "terminal"

Then terminal "{#terminal}" is connected
Then operator selects terminal "{#terminal}"
```

This is the ParameterTypes class:

```
public class ParameterTypes {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParameterTypes.class);
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Autowired
  private MemoryTagService memoryTagService;

  @DefaultParameterTransformer
  @DefaultDataTableCellTransformer
  @DefaultDataTableEntryTransformer
  public Object defaultTransformer(Object fromValue, Type toValueType) {
    var stringValue = (String) fromValue;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(MemoryTagService.MEMORY_TAG_REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringValue);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
      list.add(matcher.group());
    }
    for (String match : list) {
      String fromMemory = memoryTagService.getFromMemory(match);
      if (fromMemory != null) {
        LOGGER.debug("Found memory tag [{}] with value[{}]", match, fromMemory);
        fromValue = stringValue.replace(match, fromMemory);
      } else {
        Assert.fail("A Memory tag (" + match + ") was provided, but no value was found in memory!");
      }
    }
    return objectMapper.convertValue(fromValue, objectMapper.constructType(toValueType));
  }

  @ParameterType(value = "true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE")
  public Boolean booleanValue(String value) {
    return Boolean.valueOf(value);
  }

}
```

This is the relevant code in the steps class:

```
public class MyStepsClass {

      @Given("terminal {string} is connected") // Does NOT work
      //@Given("^terminal \"([^\"]*)\" is connected$") // Does work
      public void terminalIsConnected(String terminalLogicalId) {
        boolean isConnected = ptlService.isConnected(terminalLogicalId);
        etc.
      }

etc
}
```

I also tried adding the below in the ParameterType class, but that does not change anything:

```
  @ParameterType("^{#.*}$")
  public String stringConversion(String memoryString) {
    return defaultTransformer(memoryString, Object.class).toString();
  }

  @ParameterType(value = ".*")
  public Object stringValue(String memoryString) {
    return defaultTransformer(memoryString, String.class);
  }
```

Comment: Instead of using the default transformer, have you considered using a dedicated `@ParameterType` for the terminal type instead?

Comment: I did (added the code here above), but that does not make a difference

Comment: You  currently aren't using the the parameter type in your step definition